Add vlc package installer to python Pyinstaller python app
I know pyinstaller can't include external packages, but I have a Python app (with tkinter) witch needs VLC installed (as python-vlc requires).
Given that, once made pyinstaller app (folders, packages and exe), it seems to be all ready to be simply copied to host-pc (no further installation-steps required)..
There is a free installer witch can include a pyinstaller-compiled-app and also ask to install vlc if not installed on host-pc?
It is a good way to solve?
there are good alternatives?
Any suggestion is wellcome,
Tank you.

I saw NSIS  (Nullsoft Scriptable Install System) shoid have a vlc injection script to do that, but I have errors during trying it:  Invalid command: "@HAVE_WIN64_TRUE@"
someone can give me some useful guide link to understand this command?
